# the application in US through the PCT

Tags: pct

We are filing the national stage application in US through the PCT.
We have prepared the documents

/Specification(in English)
/Claims
/Abstract
/Drawings
/ApplicationDataSheet
/PrimaryAmendment
/IDS
/pto-1390
/sb0020glbl

What additional documents are required to be submitted through the EFS-Web ?

We must submit the PCT in foreign country?

Comment: Are you asking whether you require to submit any other documents at the USPTO? Do you also wish to know whether you can file national phase applications in other countries in addition to filing it in the US?

Comment: Thank you for your response.Yes,we require to submit any other documents at the USPTO.We

Comment: We think it is full to submit the follow documents /Specification(in English) /Claims /Abstract /Drawings /ApplicationDataSheet /PrimaryAmendment /IDS /pto-1390 /sb0020glbl.It is right?

Comment: AFAIK, you might additionally require to submit (within 30 months from the priority date) an inventor's oath or declaration, copy of amendments (if any) to the claims under Article 19 of the PCT, copy of the International Search Report, an English language translation of the annexes of the International Preliminary Examination Report (IPER), Micro Entity certification (if any), credit card payment form (Form PTO-2038) and Power of Attorney (if any) among others. You may visit the link http://www.wipo.int/pct/guide/en/gdvol2/annexes/us.pdf for further details.